# Склонение названия города: в Кривом Роге или в Кривом Рогу?

Tags: склонение

-

Answer (score 2):

Только "в Кривом Роге".
На имена собственные правила склонения отдельных составляющих топонима не переносятся.

Впрочем, даже вне топонима "в рогу" выглядит довольно экзотически. Обычно используется общий вариант предложного падежа - "в роге".

Answer (score 0):

Я бы написала в Кривом Роге

Answer (score 0):

В Кривом Рогу. См. справочник Д. Э. Розенталя по правописанию и литературной правке для работников печати, с. 193. Формы с окончанием ***-у-(-ю-)*** употребляются, если при существительном (мужского рода, неодушевлённом) имеются предлоги *-в-* и *-на-*: например, *в Крыму, на Дону, в Кривом Рогу*.

Comment: Формы на -у редко употребляютчя для имен собственных (на Дону и в Крыму  - одни из немногих, связаны с древностью топонима), а слово "рог"  имеет нормативные формы "в роге" даже для нарицательного имени..Вы некорректно обобщили то, что в действительности имеет характер частного случая. Далеко не все слова имеют подобные формы.