# Как правильно: в Кривом Роге или в Кривом Рогу?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Как правильно говорить: в Кривом Роге или в Кривом Рогу?

Answer (score 1):

В географических названиях обычно употребляется окончание Е, поэтому "в Кривом Роге". Окончание У является исключительным, например: в Крыму, в Клину, на Дону. Возможно, "в Гремячем Логу" тоже относится к исключениям. В то же время для топонимов возможно индивидуальное решение. Например, в Красноярске есть современный ЖК "Гремячий Лог", там вывешивают такие объявления: Квартиру в "Гремячем Логе" можно купить, взяв ипотечный кредит в любом банке.
Если говорить в общем, то окончание Е - это основное окончание существительных в   П.п., а окончание У - вариантное окончание(значение бывшего местного падежа), и вот для географических названий оно применяется не часто.

Еще вариант "на Украине - в Украине" очень любопытен - не знаю, обсуждали его здесь или нет.
ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
В одной политической передаче  говорили о том, что украинцы обижаются на выражение "на Украину", так как предлог НА обозначает территорию, а не самостоятельное государство. Например, мы говорим "поехать на Псковщину", здесь предлог В неуместен.

Comment: *Еще вариант "на Украине - в Украине" очень любопытен...* Всю жизнь люди жили "на Украине". Или это всю жизнь было неправильно? "На Урале" же продолжают жить до сих пор. И ничего...

Comment: Вариант *в Украине* очень широко использовался ранее :  
> Н. В. Гоголь. Ночь перед Рождеством (1831-1832 Есть такие, что имеют жен в Польше; есть такие, что имеют жен в Украине; есть такие, что имеют жен и в Турещине».

Н. В. Гоголь. Страшная месть (1831-1832 Порядку нет в Украине: полковники и есаулы грызутся, как собаки, между собой. 

О. М. Сомов. Киевские ведьмы (1833) Чертов палец ― ископаемое, находимое весьма часто в Украине.
В. Ф. Одоевский. Косморама (1837)  Я отвечал ей, что у меня в Украине также есть небольшая усадьба, и мы скоро увидели, что были довольно близкими соседями.

Comment: *Еще вариант "на Украине - в Украине" очень любопытен - не знаю, обсуждали его здесь или нет.* Где его только не обсуждали...
Даже не хочется повторяться. Смысл один: когда политика начинает влиять на лингвистику, добра (или хотя бы взаимопонимания) не жди.

Answer (score 0):

В Кривом Роге.

Во-первых, повтор вопроса:  [Склонение названия города: в Кривом Роге или в Кривом Рогу?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7312/)

Во-вторых,местный падеж можно употреблять не для  всех существительных, а только определённой семантики :

I. Предлог в  - вместилища :

- открытые вместилища: паз, [щель], пах , [горсть, дверь]; в том числе сосуды: таз, oчан; углубления рельефа: ров,пруд
- замкнутые пустые "контейнеры": гроб , шкаф, [печь, oсеть]
- помещения с некоторой специализированной функцией: хлев, цех, терем, [клеть]
- небольшие замкнутые объекты-вместилища: глаз, нос, рот, лоб, мозг, [грудь], зоб, стог, пол
- отрезки времени: год, час, [ночь]

II. Пространства (предлог в)

- "точки" (населенные пункты и другие места интенсивной компактной деятельности людей): скит, oфорт, (аэро)порт; топоним Клин
- "районы" (обширные участки пространства, с которыми связана определенная деятельность): тыл, ад, рай

-"места" (обширные участки географического пространства): край1, [степь, даль, тишь]; топоним Крым

- "объемные" участки поверхности: сад, бор, лес, [тень, oсень]
- части пространств или объектов (в последнем случае со сдвоенной таксономической характеристикой): низ, [глубь], зад, перёд, верх,бок, угол

III. Конфигурации объектов, образующих устойчивые структуры (предлог в)
 - ряд 'линия', oкруг (также в значении 'тесное сообщество'), строй, полк, рой, род

Кроме того,предлоги в или на - вещества и ситуации

Топоним Кривой Рог не происходит от сущ. с вышеназванными значениями . Поэтому В Гремячем Логу , но в Кривом Роге.

Comment: Людмила, "рог" - здесь "изгиб", "излучина реки".  
Так что существительное по вашей системе вполне себе подходящее для местного падежа. Но все проще. 
Отнюдь Не все такие существительные допускают местный падеж.  
Рог - как раз из числа тех, что требуют обычного предложного.   
Остальное - согласен.

ЗЫ Я поправил у Вас ссылку.